# Error Creating Vault - Missing S3 Bucket Flag?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, jenkins-x

I'm trying to create a new jenkinsx cluster using jx. This is the command I am running:

```
jx create cluster aws --ng
```

And this is the error I get:

```
error: creating the system vault: creating vault: Missing S3 bucket flag
```

It seems to fail out on creating the vault due to missing a bucket flag, and I'm not sure how to remedy that.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
jx create cluster aws --ng --state s3://<bucket_name>
```

Also, ensure you are using [the latest release](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/releases/tag/v1.3.86)

Comment: Yes, I tried it with the --state flag, I still get the error :(

Comment: I am guessing you already ensured access to the bucket from wherever you are running the jx command. Can you try to copy something to the s3 bucket from the same location and as same user from where you are running the jx command? Does that succeed?

Comment: Also try interchanging the options in the command as below ```jx create cluster aws  --state s3://<bucket_name> --ng ```

Comment: Tried both of these, and it doesn't fix unfortunately.

Comment: As I mentioned in my earlier answer, ensure you are using the latest version. I was able to run the command ```jx create cluster aws --ng``` without any errors. I am using versions as below NAME               VERSION
jx                 2.0.123
Kubernetes cluster v1.12.7
kubectl            v1.13.0
git                git version 2.19.0.windows.1